# Use cases of UUPS proxies over Transparent?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

What are the use cases where UUPS proxies are more suitable apart from achieving immutability as the logic to update the contract resides in the Logic contract rather than proxies.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would first advise you to take a look at this tutorial: [UUPS tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-uups-proxy-pattern-upgrade-smart-contracts/) as it contains good info relevant to this question.

However... before comparing **UUPS** and **Transparent Proxy** patterns, it's essential to understand the concept of `signature collision` .

Initial implementations of **Proxy pattern**, had some logic written inside the storage (proxy) contract. However, because **EVM** reads functions by **hashing** them and taking the first **4 bytes** as the `function signature`. There is a potential for two **completely different** function to have **the same** `signature`.

So, while you might see a function as `fakeFunction()`, the **EVM** sees it as the first 4 bytes of `keccak256(fakeFunction())` ==> `0x762eccf7`.

This can lead to `function/signature collisions`. A case when two **different** functions have the **same 4 bytes** at the start of the hash. In some cases, this has caused a breakdown in contract functionality when a user mistakenly calls a function in storage instead of the implementation. Even worse, this presents a security issue.

Two design patterns were introduced to tackle this problem:

**Transparent Proxy Pattern:**

- Allows identical function signatures in the proxy and logic contract
- Delegate calls to the logic contract only occur if the caller is not
  a contract admin.
- If the caller is a contract admin, the function is invoked in the
  proxy contract itself or reverts if it doesn't exist.
- Comparatively easier to implement and widely used. (**debatable**)
- Requires more gas for deployment.

**UUPS Proxy Pattern:**

- Upgrades are triggered via the logic contract rather than the proxy
  contract.
- Uses a unique storage slot in the proxy contract to store the address
  of the logic contract.
- Offers flexibility to remove upgradeability.
- More gas-efficient than the Transparent Proxy pattern.
- Not as commonly used as it is relatively new, and extra care is required
  for the upgrade logic (access control) as it resides in the
  implementation contract. (**debatable**)
- One of the original motivations for UUPS was to deploy many smart
  contract wallets on the mainnet, where the logic could be deployed
  once and the proxy could be deployed multiple times for each new
  wallet, saving gas.

**When to choose UUPS over Transparent Proxy?**

The choice between **UUPS** and **Transparent Proxy** patterns depends on factors such as:

- **Gas efficiency:** UUPS is more gas-efficient compared to Transparent Proxy.
- **Flexibility:** UUPS offers the ability to remove upgradeability.
- **Implementation complexity:** Transparent Proxy is comparatively easier to implement and more widely used.

**OpenZeppelin** suggests using the **UUPS** pattern due to its `gas efficiency` and suitability for deploying many smart contract wallets on the mainnet, thus saving gas.

I heard many advising **Transparent Proxy** as it's "easier" to implement. And that might be the point if not for the fact **UUPS** has been developed for quite some time and is heavily supported by both **OpenZeppelin** and **Hardhat**. Both of these offer you a number of libraries you can use to implement and maintain your **UUPS contracts** without much hassle.

Comment: This answer is actually completely wrong.  The *whole point* of the transparent proxy pattern is to solve the collision problem by having a proxy admin.  The proxy only delegates to the implementation (logic) contract when `msg.sender` is not the proxy admin.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Thanks for pointing that out. I will have to double-check my answers.  It looks like I explained UUPS vs Proxy pattern instead of UUPS vs Transparent Proxy pattern.  But I was positive I had read somewhere about exploits regarding Transparent Proxy. So I will take a look at that again. And if that turns to be wrong I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of exploits in OpenZeppelin's Transparent Proxy. There was a gap in their instructions that also occurred with UUPS (taking ownership of a logic contract with `initialize` and doing `self-destruct`). With a transparent proxy, you can recover by upgrading (you'd also need delegatecall logic to be exposed). With UUPS, "oops", you can't since your upgrade mechanism is in the destroyed contract, so the proxy is bricked. See: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/uupsupgradeable-vulnerability-post-mortem/15680. EIP-1822 is worth a read, as I think it highlights some pitfalls in this topic.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh I edited my answer; please review it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pros and Cons of both solutions

- **UUPS deployment is cheaper**.
  Upgradeability mechanism logic (code) is written in the implementation/logic contract, so less code on the Proxy side. Valuable when deploying multiple proxy contracts that use the same implementation contract.
- **The upgradeability mechanism can be modified or removed** in UUPS proxies.
  This is again because the upgradeability mechanism logic (code) is written in the implementation/logic contract and it is the one that can be replaced by another contract.
- The pros of the **Transparent proxy** are that it is **relatively easier for implementation and more battle-tested** (UUPS are a newer concept) but OpenZepplin recommends using their UUPS proxy implementation instead of the older Transparent Proxy.

#### Additional info

Both Transparent vs UUPS Proxies have one main property - they allow for one contract's code (implementation/logic contract) to be able to modify the storage (state) of another contract (proxy contract).

The same property means they have the same use cases. The most used of them are:

- Save huge amounts of gas by deploying only one implementation/logic contract and as many proxy contracts as you need.
- Make upgradeable smart contracts

**NB!** UUPS is by design upgradeable proxy pattern while OpenZeppelin's Transparent proxy is not upgradeable by default. For the purpose of this question, I will assume that we are talking about a Transparent Upgradeable proxy.

The difference between the two methods is in the way they achieve the above property. The different implementations lead to the explained above **pros and cons of both solutions**:

I will not add the implementations' details because this is not what is asked in this question, but you can learn more here:

- [UUPS Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1822)
- [Proxy Storage Slots Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1967)
- [OpenZeppelin Docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/api/proxy#transparent-vs-uups)